# how to distinguish between "file download url" and normal url in WKWebview policyForNavigation Method?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

Am using WKWebView to display googledrive, i need to handle download files using WKWebView Delegates.
Here is my Code:

```
 - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
  {
    if(DOWNLOAD_FILE_URL)
    [handler downloadFileFromURL:navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString]; 
  }
```

The url not having any extension at the end of the path.
Eg.[Check this link](https://doc-10-1o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/rsebnjj86k199vha69qbhqotj7h8bls5/3tgnvcao5c8f3pml4enl29dtlfgoqvet/1484301600000/07380150970254722458/07380150970254722458/0BykAaNOeMb0LREZMNDZvTkhIU0U?h=07742201912213815930&e=download)
The above URL is an image File URL but i can't recognise it in "policyForNavigation" method to force it to download.

Help me to find the proper if condition...

> "if(DOWNLOAD_FILE_URL)"

Any help to find the difference between File URL and normal url are appreciated.
Then only i can send it to download method.

Thanks in Advance.
@Alex Wayne , @community wiki

Comment: did u get the answer for this @Jeba moses